# Build Failed - validate build/release

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Just a few days ago I could both run (in the simulator and on my iphone device) and package my iOS app for the iOS iTunes Store. But now I cannot get past this error during package:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Validate build/Release-iphoneos/Trivia\ Rain.app
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/natej/.appcelerator/install/4.1.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:84:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

Since a few days ago when the package worked perfectly, I have changed nothing related to my keychains, keystore, profiles, certificates, etc. I have made a few code changes, but after my changes, the app compiled fine, runs in simulator, and deploys/runs on my iphone 6 device. I have double checked that my certs and distribution profiles are all valid, and nothing has changed from a few days ago.

I have cleaned my project, restarted Appcelerator Studio, restarted my mac. Still I cannot get past this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Troubleshooting ? Does the debug/trace level logs give you anything useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back 4 days later after having these problems, having changed nothing (no code, no settings, no Appcelerator updates)...and it simply worked this time.

In summary, Appcelerator is buggy. :-|

Comment: are you using appc? There were some 'license/connection problems' some days/weeks ago

Comment: the tool that appcelerator studio uses to compile your app. If you are on the indie plan or one of the newer plans that you are using the official appc tool (in comparison to the open source tool: titanium). But the connection problems might have been the problem if everything is working fine now.

Comment: Got it. Why the **** doesn't appcelerator code in a nice message for the developer when their server is offline or having problems? Frustrating to chase a phantom and waste time.